# MongoDB complex polygon with a hole

Tags: mongodb, performance, maps, polygon

I'm wondering is there a way to query complex polygon with a hole. Example:

```
[
  [
    // hole rectangle
    [ 59.187, 42.891 ],
    [ 59.187, 13.997 ],
    [ 46.377, 13.997 ],
    [ 46.377, 42.891 ]
  ],
  [
    // border rectangle
    [ 63.802, 57.964 ],
    [ 63.802, 0.176 ],
    [ 37.719, 0.176 ],
    [ 37.719, 57.964 ]
  ]
]
```

I'm talking about geospatial queries:

```
$geoWithin: {
    $polygon: polygon
}
```

I heard of a way to group intersects in different queries, but it seems not very performance to me, so maybe I missed something. So I'm looking for a way to query in the non-hole (highlighted) area:
[image]

Comment: I was hoping array.flat() could help, but no

Comment: I think you have to run 2 query stages, one `$geoWithin` for the outer region and then remove the inner region. Or use 3rd party library, e.g. [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

For now I'll proceed with the next tricky sort of thing:

[image]

I flatten these arrays and add few more points to make it a single solid polygon with minimal distance between sides. Once I test performance of this thing and compare it with other ways (like query everything and remove unneeded), I'll update this comment.